# Limiting number of collect_list items in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have code that states

```
db.groupBy("ids")
  .agg(collect_list("names") as "alias")
  .select("ids", "alias")
```

However, there are some rows where the alias would be only 1 entry large, while others could be 200.

How can I limit the ones with >30 entries to a maximum of 30 entries?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [slice](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#slice) function to subset the array.

```
db.groupBy("ids")                       
  .agg(slice(collect_list("names"), 1, 30) as "alias")
  .select("ids", "alias")
```

Comment: will this work even if some of the lists would never get to 30 entries? Some lists could be 1 entry large while others could be 200, and only when there are >30 entries is when I would want to make it 30

Comment: It works fine with array elements less than 30.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Apache DataFu](https://github.com/apache/datafu/tree/main/datafu-spark) *collectLimitedList* UDF. I think it's better than using *slice*, because if your list is huge you could run out of memory if you execute *collect_list* before slicing.

You would use it like this:

```
db.groupBy("ids")
  .agg(collectLimitedList("names", 30) as "alias")
  .select("ids", "alias")
```

Disclaimer: I'm a member of Apache DataFu.